# Getting started with nhibernate, informix and fluentmapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, informix

I need to configure NHibernate 3.1 to target an informix 11.50 database in an asp.net 4.0 application
using Fluent NHibernate for mappings.

I have this connection string:  jdbc:informix-sqli://server:1530/database:informixserver=lufi_tcp
and I have the user an pass. I can connect to to the database using dbvisualizer.

I tray some examples of configuracion that I find on the Internet but it dosen't work.

Can someone get my a link or informacion about what I need to do for
configure nhibernate with fluent to target an informix database (for dummies, please.)

S.O: Windows 8 64 bits

Thanks you in advance.

More information:

I Build the session factory in this way:

```
 class FluentNHibernateLocalSessionFactory : LocalSessionFactoryObject
{
    public string[] FluentNhibernateMappingAssemblies { get; set; }

    protected override ISessionFactory NewSessionFactory(Configuration config)
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(
                 IfxSQLIConfiguration
                .Informix1000
                .Provider<NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider>()
                .Driver<NHibernate.Driver.IfxDriver>()
                .Dialect<NHibernate.Dialect.InformixDialect>()
                .ConnectionString("Database=myDatabase;Server=myServer:1530;Persist Security      Info=True;Authentication=Server;uid=myUser;password=myPass;")
                .ShowSql()
            )
            .Mappings(m =>
            {
                foreach (string assemblyName in FluentNhibernateMappingAssemblies)
                    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.Load(assemblyName));
            })
           .BuildConfiguration()
           .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

The error I get:

**{"Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.IfxDriver, NHibernate, Version=3.1.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4."}**

Comment: Do not ask for links or code without showing what you tried so far, otherwise this post will be closed... How do you build the nhibernate session factory? Are you using the correct dialect? What is the error? Why are you using an old version of NH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a reference to `IBM.Data.Informix` otherwise the driver will throw this exception. To do so you have to add a reference to IBM.Data.Informix.dll to the project which is running your code above.

Comment: Thanks, I now get a new error. I've updated the question to show the error.

Comment: please mark this q as answered, remove your edit and ask a new question for your update because this is a completely different topic (any maybe google for the error before)

Comment: This fragment of the connection string: "myServer:1530" indicates that you want to connect with DRDA driver because SQLI driver doesn't handle port here. If my guess is correct than you need: make sure IBM.Data.Informix is DRDA driver and change IfxSQLIConfiguration to IfxDRDAConfiguration. Alternatively (if you want SQLI): make sure IBM.Data.Informix is SQLI driver and Server=<name of informix configuration set>, for example ol_ifxservertcp.